# How do I add a conditional set clause to a slonik sql query?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, slonik

I'm building a postgres query using [slonik](https://github.com/gajus/slonik) to update a user table.
The `passwordHash` column should be changed only if the `passwordHash` variable is not `null`, otherwise it should be left untouched.

I've tried with a nested rule:

```
import { createPool, sql } from 'slonik'

const dbPool = createPool()

const updateUser = await dbPool.connect(async (conn) => {
  return conn.one(sql`
    UPDATE users 
    SET "name" = ${name},
      "email" = ${email},
      ${passwordHash ? sql`"passwordHash" = ${passwordHash},` : ''}
    WHERE "id" = ${id} 
    RETURNING *
  `)
})
```

But I'm getting the error: `syntax error at or near "$3"`

What's the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

probably a bit late, but you could use `coalesce`.

```js
const updateUser = await dbPool.connect(async (conn) => {
  return conn.one(sql`
    UPDATE users 
    SET "name" = ${name},
      "email" = ${email},
      "passwordHash" = coalesce(${passwordHash}, passwordHash)
    WHERE "id" = ${id} 
    RETURNING *
  `)
})
```

if `passwordHash` can also be `undefined`, go `coalesce(${passwordHash ?? null}, passwordHash)`